# How would I add a file to a GitHub repository that was not tracked as a change by the Visual Studio 2019 extension?

Tags: git, github

I have had a hickup in the Visual Studio 2019 Extension for GitHub that destroyed my local repository.

I had just finished a new class.

I expected to see the .sln and .cs as changes.

- I went to Team Explorer and clicked changes.
- Team Explorer reported "No Changes".
- I went to the Branches and did a View History.
- The extension reported "No History".

The local repository was gone - not even a solution.  I would like to recover the months of history if at all possible. I have found that old-fashioned off-line backups make with every commit can be a God-send.

Is there any way to add files that are not tracked as changes to a repository from the extension?